# SharePoint 2013 Webparts Icon display issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Ive added webparts to my SharePoint site, the "recently changed webpart"
[image: webpart image with the ? icon]

and another webpart like "Items matching a Tag"
[![webpart with ? icon][2]][2]

I want to change the "?" or plain grey background displayed in these webparts to a custom image or something else.

I've tried editing the webparts and tried changing the icon (maybe im not doing it right and i need help with this)

I have tried giving an image url in the advanced section of the webpart settings 
[image]

I want to display an image instead of the "?" icon.

How would I go about and do it.
Would I be able to do it in the SharePoint Designer, If so, please advice.

Answer (score -1):

Since your last modified item was DispForm.aspx there's no image associated with form pages. Had the item been an image, it would probably show the thumbnail. 
You'd have to customize the display template for the web part and change the logic where no images are found. You probably also need to adjust some CSS.

Display templates can be found under:
     Master Page Gallery > Display Templates > Content Web Parts

Comment: the location Master Page Gallery > Display Templates > Content Web Parts said there are no files in thi sfolder when I tried to access it from SharePoint Designer.@aveenav

Comment: Use the browser or open with Explorer option (in IE).

Comment: This answer doesn't tell you *how* to change the icons, which is what the original question asks. After arriving here after looking at search results for the same thing the OP is looking for, I find this answer disappointing.

Comment: Those are the directions, not a complete solution. What's disappointing is some people want plug-n-play solution without providing any effort.